# Python on Windows, installing 3dr solo command line, PermissionError: [Errno 13]

Tags: python, permission-denied, 3dr

I am trying to install 3DR solo command line on Windows 10.  Below is the exception that i get.  i have been doing a lot of reading and googling.  I couldnt figure out the permission denied problem.  I have this part  shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile), but i still get denied.

Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)

File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run
    root=options.root_path,

File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 646, in install
    **kwargs

File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 803, in
    install self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)

File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 998, in
    move_wheel_files isolated=self.isolated,

File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 339, in
  move_wheel_files clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

File "c:\python35\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 317, in clobber
***shutil.copyfile(srcfile, destfile)***

File "c:\python35\lib\shutil.py", line 115, in copyfile
    with open(dst, 'wb') as fdst:

***PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\python35\Lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win32.pyd'***

Answer (score 0):

This is going to sound simple but are you running an elevated command line?

Comment: That's what i thought at first, so i ran as administrator.  but i still get denied.

Answer (score 0):

If you are upgrading the cffi package i.e. you had it already installed and doing `pip install xyz` package that is trying to upgrade cffi to its last version, all you have to do is simply
delete: `c:\python35\Lib\site-packages\_cffi_backend.cp35-win32.pyd` then try again.